# Internal Server Error on using python on web server with cpanel

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, webserver, cpanel

I am newer to python. I have cpanel. I have written this basic code and uploaded on cgi-bin folder on my web server

```
#! /usr/bin/python
 print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
 print "<html>Hello world!</html>" '
```

but on executing this page on browser it is giving

> **Internal Server Error**

I have changed permission of my script to 777 but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Trying running that code directly from the python console..

You should see this **SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal**

```
print "<html>Hello world!</html>"
```

You have an extra '

Comment: Thanks for your early initiatives.

I have sorted it out.

I have added a new .htaccess in the same folder and it started working.